# 50 ohms output termination for a 50ohms load?

Tags: function-generator

Would the voltage measured at the 50 ohms still be doubled to the reading on the function generator?

I am new to the concept, from what I know, the 50ohms function generator outputs double the voltage if it is connected to a oscilloscope that has high input impedance. If now we were to use the 50 ohms function generator for a 50 ohms load and then measure the voltage drop on the load, would the resulting voltage still be doubled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *If now we were to use the 50 ohms function generator for a 50 ohms
> load and then measure the voltage drop on the load, would the
> resulting voltage still be doubled?*

No, the signal generator's 50 Ω output impedance and the 50 Ω load form a 2:1 potential divider and that means that the voltage seen across the load is precisely what the signal generator's display is saying it should be i.e. not double (as seen with a high impedance load such as an oscilloscope).

So, if the signal generator is set to deliver 1 volt RMS then, when connected to the appropriate load resistor (usually 50 Ω) then you will get 1 volt RMS across the load.

Comment: Oh, so the 50 ohms terminator is actually designed for situation like this (a 50 ohms load). If I try to switch it to high impedance mode, the voltage reading for the load would actually be halved?

Comment: @Kevin if your signal generator has the facility to switch to a higher impedance output (sometimes 600 &ohm; for example), then the voltage across a load of 600 &ohm; would be the same. Not sure I fully understood your comment so, if that doesn't help, try re-phrasing.

Comment: I mean without changing the source resistor. In 50 ohms mode the function generator is outputting twice the displayed voltage, so by voltage division, the voltage measure at the load is same as what is displayed. If I switch the function generator to high z mode, the generator what output the same voltage as displayed, so the voltage drop on the load would be halved (the other half is dropped at the source resistor). Correct me if I am wrong, thank you.

Comment: If you switch the generator to high impedance mode then you will not get any signal output voltage into a load and maybe a few mV (basically noise artefacts) into an open circuit @Kevin

Answer (score 4):

The voltage on a

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiOmjd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuit.*

The source and load resistor form a 2:1 voltage divider.

Measurement of V<sub>O</sub> without a load will result in a reading of twice the rated output. In other words, the output is only calibrated when running a 50 Ω load.

Answer (score 1):

The signal generator provides 2*Display Volts, where Display is the voltage seen on the signal generator's display. Now if the signal generator is terminated with a 50 ohms load the measured voltage across the load is 50/(50+50)*(2*Display)=Display, assuming a 50 ohms output impedance for the generator. If connected to a high impedance load you get 2*Display Volts at the output, which is twice the voltage seen on the display.