S21 calculation
In this post
It mentioned that there's a factor 2 in S21 value.
But I'm still don't understand why there's a 2 in it.
My schematic is shown below.

Shouldn't S21 = Vout/Vgen?
My question is: where is the impedance that caused a factor of 2 in above circuit?

"factor 2" in a search of the referenced post found no matches.

Sorry, I referenced the wrong page and have corrected it

Hint: suppose you replace your DUT with a simple wire from port 1 to port 2. What should $S_{21}$ be? What do you measure for $V_{out}/V_{gen}$? Do you understand why?

@ThePhoton Ok, now I understand what causes the reason behind the factor of 2. I have seen this post before: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550000/50-ohms-output-termination-for-a-50ohms-load. Is it the same concept too?

Yes, that's the same concept.
